# C# compare algorithms

Tags: c#, algorithm, diff

Are there any open source algorithms in c# that solve the problem of creating a difference between two text files?

It would be super cool if it had some way of highlighting what exact areas where changed in the text document also.

Answer (score 16):

There's also a c# port of Google's (Neil Fraser) [diff, match and patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/).

Answer (score 13):

There is [Menees Diff](http://www.menees.com/Diff.Net.htm) which will provide you with a C# diff implementation.  The source code is included.  I've used it in the past with good success wrapping it in my own implemenation.

Answer (score 9):

How about this one? : [DIFFPLEX](https://github.com/mmanela/diffplex)

Answer (score 7):

Check out [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff). Here it is [in the gnu project](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/diffutils.html) (open source, of course), and many more links to implementations are found in the wikipedia article. A comparison of different such programs is found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools).

Comment: This is not a C# implementation

Answer (score 6):

check this link 
"good line by line Diff Algorithm "
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/diffengine.aspx