# Is there an open source diff library for .NET (for text)?

Tags: .net, open-source, diff

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C# compare algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199/c-compare-algorithms)
>   [Any decent text diff/merge engine for .NET ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138331/any-decent-text-diff-merge-engine-for-net)

I'm looking for a way to programmatically diff two text files.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199/c-compare-algorithms

Comment: @Onkelborg: Thanks, looks like the answers to that question will help me. Voting to close.

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138331/any-decent-text-diff-merge-engine-for-net as well?