# How to tag text, to keep track of unique edits

Tags: tagging

So, for example in database I have three users: Peter, John and Sara. There is a specific field, in which all three users can write.
Peter writes:

> "I like apples"

, after that John appends with

> " and I like bananas"

. Now I have field which says

> "I like apples and I like bananas"

, so If I would like to display, which part was writen by whom, my approuch would be to create html tags:
The field would be:

```
<span class="text-sequence-1">I like apples</span><span class="text-sequence-2"> and I like bananas</span>
```

and then, from database I would pick the sentences by its order and using CSS on hover on display additional content, on each  part of hover on.

1. 1st problem. The problem is if, the third user, Sara, comes and
   updates the text, which belongs to both original. Which can be
   overcome if I allow to edit one by one Johns and Peters  tags.
   Then I get edited span inside of original spans and could track
   which part was edited and how. If I did like this, I would still
   face a second problem:
2. 2nd problem. If Sara decides to edit, for example Johns part, a few
   times. I would still get nested  badly.
   I could use something like #number tags instead of spans, so I can track where each edition ends, but then I couldn't apply CSS code to them to color which part belongs to who and apply additional effects on hover, like showing a box, who edited it and when.
   Any ideas how could I implement it?
   Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Gacek is right - this is *not* the way to do it, and will break down very quickly if a few persons change individual letters or copy and paste text around. Rainbow-colored text would quickly lose any meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a database, keep track of the edits in a separate table. For each edit, keep the following fields:

- row-ID of this edit (primary key)
- the parent row-ID (the row-ID of the "current edit" when the edit was started/confirmed; see below for how to use)
- the author that edited things
- the time-stamp
- an optional short text describing what was changed (for example, "fixed spelling")

When showing the field, you can then display a link to a "history", that would show who edited what when. You can show [individual differences between any two versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=2014_FIFA_World_Cup&action=history) such as Wikipedia does when you look at the history of a page - there are many libraries to do that, with highlighting and all. [This library](http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/) seems nice, but there are [many others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462609/looking-for-a-javascript-visual-diff-lib), in all sorts of languages.

When someone starts to edit, let them modify the then-current version (highest time-stamp). When they commit their edit (click `accept` or similar), check again to see that nobody else has changed things while they were editing (the time-stamp of the parent edit is still highest). If someone *did* change something, show them the difference between your parent-row and the edit, and tell them to fix things before committing (there may be *several* edits to take into account). This is the "wikipedia way", and it amounts to a sort of lightweight version control (much easier to implement than, say, `Git`)

Answer (score 1):

Acually I think that this approach is not good. As you noticed you will get alot of nasty nestings.

What if somone edits only one letter?

Instead of that, think about line comparison approach. Like Git does. So compare if first line changed and store each version.( More sophisticated way would be only storing lines that changed and applying changes like git patches.)

I think your way is destined to fail. It's far way too complex and there is no logical comparision method to be used.

`John is cool`
`John is uncool`
`John is Uncool`
`John is weak`

Think how you would tag those. What if somone deletes piece of text? Edit will not be visible or u will insert an empty tag (which will not be visible)?

Dont tag, compare. Tagging is not what you're looking for i think. Also please see: [Text comparison algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065536/text-comparison-algorithm)

Comment: I fully agree that spans will not work. However, I think that git is overkill

Comment: Not Git. Gitlike comparision. Line by line comparision.

Comment: Ah - the "store each version" and "git patches" references got me confused.

Comment: This makes so much more sense now. So, WHAT IF... I take original_text and updated_text and scan like this:
starting from symbol[0] in original_text and add symbol by symbol to my array and keep adding while I can find this symbols sequence in updated_text, then collect longest possible such arrays into text, from this point I would know, which part doesn't belong to any original_text part, and again, somehow I mark it (how)? Would this approuch take too much resources and execution time?
Edit: Once I wrote It new messages appeared, I'll  read them.

Comment: @user3565320 you can figure out a diff algorithm on your own, but it is hard to get right & make it run fast. Use an existing one (see links in my answer)