# Aligning two dataframes to improve matching accuracy in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, string-matching

Suppose I have two dataframes which look like this:

```
df1
ID  Chr
1   a
2   a
3   a
4   a
5   a
6   a
7   b
8   b
9   b
10  b
11  c
12  c
13  a
14  a
15  a
16  a
17  c
18  c
19  c
20  a
```

```
df2
ID Chr
1   a
2   a
3   b
4   b
5   b
6   b
7   b
8   b
9   b
10  b
11  c
12  c
13  a
14  a
15  c
16  c
17  c
18  a
19  a
20  a
```

If you look at the two dfs you can see that they are quite similar. In fact if it is like this i consider them part of the same set. But the issue is that they are not aligned too well. In this small sample it might not seem like a big deal but with the actual data with more than 1000 rows the alignment is a big problem.

The issue is that my matching algorithm is pretty basic and compares one row of the `df1` to the corresponding row of `df2` and gives a score of 1 is there is a match and 0 for a mismatch. What complicates the issue is that I'm not matching all the rows of the dataframes at once either. Due to the circumstances I have to do partial matches. For example with the above data I would match by 5 rows. The first five rows of `df1` against five rows of `df2`. When I minimize the scale the issue becomes worse.

So the question is can I do something about the alignment without having to resort to matching the entire dfs at once.

Comment: Are you searching for something like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065536/text-comparison-algorithm)?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly. 
If you only want to compare the `chr` colums you could join the two tables and then check for the `chr` columns.

This is very easy if you use the `dplyr` package. 
First I create some toy data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:5, chr = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"))
df2 <- data.frame(id = 1:5, chr = c("a", "b", "b", "b", "b"))

library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = "id", suffix = c("_1", "_2")) %>% 
  mutate(flag = if_else(chr_1 == chr_2, 1, 0))

  id chr_1 chr_2 flag
1  1     a     a    1
2  2     a     b    0
3  3     a     b    0
4  4     b     b    1
5  5     b     b    1
```