# Calculate the percentage difference between two text files in c#

Tags: c#, string, text

I have two txt documents and need to find out how different they are.

What is the best algorithm for calculating the percentage difference between two text files in c#?

Comment: You may want to learn about *Levenshtein distance* **or** see how `diff` operates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the diff.c in Linux source code for the diff algorithm.

Or have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199/c-sharp-compare-algorithms)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) might be helpful. It's written in a C# and some other languages and it's open source. You also have a demo section that you can use to see if it's useful to your purpose.